# unable to use Sqlite

Tags: xcode, sqlite

i am new to sqlite i tried this things in my project

adding framework  libsqlite3.dylib

```
   #import "sqlite3.h"
-(NSString *)filepath{
    NSArray *path=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir=[path objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sql"];
}

   -(void)openDB{
    if(sqlite3_open([[self filepath] UTF8String], &db)!= SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(db);
       NSAssert(0,@"Database failed to open");
    }
}
```

but i am getting this error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Database failed to open'

Why am i getting this error ?

Comment: Hi, Where did you put the database file? Does it exist? Also how is the file named? Thank you.

Comment: sorry i had not created any database file the book i am referring just showed me to do the above things can you suggest me some good books